# ShareKit lose focus when actionsheet is closed

Tags: ios, view, focus, sharekit

I´m trying to integrate ShareKit in my ios game.

Everything is working fine and the actionsheet is shown and I can interact with it but I´m not able to return the focus to my app when the sharekit action has finished (by closing the actionsheet or finishing any action).

I have tried in several ways but any has worked for me. What´s happening?
I´m not an expert programmer so I expect I´m missing something.

I´m

This is my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SHK.h"
#import "SHKConfiguration.h"

@interface SocialWrapper: UIViewController{
}

- (id) init;
- (void) open;
- (void) dealloc;

@end
```

and .m

```
#import "SocializeWrapper.h"

@implementation SocialWrapper

- (id) init {
    self=[super init];

    DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[DefaultSHKConfigurator alloc] init];
    [SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];

    [SHK flushOfflineQueue];
    return self;
}

- (void) open
{  
    NSString *someText = @"Hello Earth!";
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];

    // Get the ShareKit action sheet
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [window addSubview:self.view];

    [SHK setRootViewController:self];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void) dealloc {
     NSLog(@"SHK dealloc");
    [self release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I´m calling it by using this wrapper

```
#import "SocializeWrapper.h"

SocialWrapper *socialize;

void SHKinit(void) {
    NSLog(@"SHK Init");    
    socialize = [[SocialWrapper alloc] init];  
}


void SHKopenWeb(void){
    NSLog(@"SHK Open actionsheet"); 
    [socialize open];
}
```

I´m working with ios 5, xcode 4.3.2 and the last sharekit version from the git.

I think I have to dissmiss my SocialWrapper once the actionsheet is closed but I don´t know how to capture that event, or even if this is correct. I´m stucked.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

### UPDATE

As comment adviced, now the controller is on a category, using the actionsheet delegate, the focus can be regained when clicking the cancel´s actionsheet button. The problem still persists when an action is finished or cancelled. Don´t know how to capture that event.

This is my category code:

```
#import "SocialWrapper.h"

@implementation UIViewController (SocialController)


-(void) loadconfig
{
    DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[DefaultSHKConfigurator alloc] init];
    [SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];

    [SHK flushOfflineQueue];
}

- (void) open
{  
    NSLog(@"Opening social button");  

    NSString *someText = @"Monkey Armada rules!";
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];

    // Get the ShareKit action sheet
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [window addSubview:self.view];

    [actionSheet setDelegate:self];

    [SHK setRootViewController:self];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
      NSLog(@"SHK actionsheet dissmiss with button %d", buttonIndex); 
     if(buttonIndex == 4)
     {
        NSLog(@"SHK close actionsheet");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
     }
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue: close from the UIActionSheet popover works OK, but finishing an action (either via cancel or successful completion) does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well since SHKActionSheet is a subclass of UIActionSheet you can set the delegate of that class to self to know when the dismissal happens.

Also, [self release]; in dealloc is complete misunderstanding of what release does, if you're in dealloc then releasing self won't do anything !
Learn the memory management rules.

I should also warn you that [window addSubview:self.view] is deprecated, you should not do that at all. In fact, I don't see a reason to wrap share kit stuff each view controller should be able to write that code easily. At worse you could put that code in a category on UIViewController if you don't want to rewrite the code every time.

Comment: Hi, I´ve followed your advice and now the code is in a category. The actionsheet is now beeing closed fine and the focus regained using the actionsheet delegate. Now the problem only persists when an action is completed (tweet/mail send or canceled, etc...) I think I must remove the view in order to gain focus but dont know where and how to do it, maybe capturing the "action finished/cancelled" event?